# Java composition - also valid for primitive type variables?

Tags: java, composition

I was reading about the composition definition, which is

"has-a", so for example a car has an engine

A composition means that a class has as one of its fields a reference type variable of another class.

What confuses me and I cannot find, if we have for example a bank account class, and we use this:

private double balance = 0.0;

We could say that an account has a balance right? Does that mean that primitive type variables can also be included in the definition of "composition"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tip for you: for any monetary values like bank account balance etc. use BigDecimal objects instead of double or float primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Association, Aggregation, **Composition**, Abstraction, Generalization, Realization, Dependency are relationship between classes. We don't use these terms for primitives variables.

Composition is "has-a" relationship between **objects**. Bank Account class has balance but balance is not an object. Therefore, we won't include this in the definition of **composition**.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more according to the bank account example. :)

Comment: Yes i thought my question was "somewhat" original as most definition of composition (that i could find at least) do not say anything about primitive type variables. I think i understand for the most part what composition means, fairly simple concept, but if the question is posed in my way, what do we call that relationship when a class has a primitive type as one of its fields? Why can we describe that relationship with the same sentence -has a- ? We could also have a "int code" and say an account has a code (even if you would use a String probably, but you get what i mean)

Comment: As per definition composition is "has-a" relationship between objects (not Java Objects). See the definition of an object in computer science:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science). So in-fact a variable of any type could be considered as object.

Comment: Association, Aggregation, Composition, Abstraction, Generalization, Realization, Dependency terms signify the relationships between classes. Balance is the attribute of Bank class. In UML diagram it will be represented as an attribute of Bank class.

Answer (score 0):

Composition is a concept and I feel it shouldn't be bounded by language specific rules.

In your example Account class is having "has-a" relationship with balance. However since a primitive type double is sufficient to represent balance, you have used primitive double in your example. But that doesn't change "has-a" relationship. So conceptually irrespective of whether variable is of primitive type or not it should be part of composition.

In the [wikipedia entry of composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Composite_types_in_C) you can see example of Composition in C where primitive is considered as part of composition.

I agree that in a typical UML diagram we might show balance as property of the Account class instead of showing it in separate block but still the balance is part of composite structure - Account.